# Kate text editor project plugin issue

Tags: text-editor, kde-plasma, kate

Hi fellow F/OSS enthusiasts, I'm having a problem with KDE's Kate. The editor won't show my project's file structure in the appropriate panel nor showing the project name in the dropdown selection for projects.

Having the ability to quickly navigate your project file is indeed a must have and I don't understand why it doesn't work. I have provided a .kateproject file at the root of my project and it has a git repository set up with the autoload from cvs enabled so technically it should load... I'm using manjaro with the latest update as of 7th of May. Kate version is 20.04.0 and `uname -a` yield : Linux  5.4.36-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 29 18:47:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux. My Desktop Environment is Plasma 5.18.4 .

[view of kate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0KbG.png)

content of .kateproject :

```
{
    "name": "Hello",
    "files": [ { "git": 1 } ],
    "index": true,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Being a Kate developer, I believe your JSON file is incorrect due to the final `,` after `true`.

Then again, you do not need the `.kateproject` file at all anymore, if you enable auto-loading of git repositories as [described here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/kate/kate-application-plugin-projects.html): `Settings`-> `Configure Kate` -> `Projects`, then tick `[x] Git` if not already checked. You then can open a git project by simply opening an arbitrary file of the git repository.